# Block a4j:support call when the input value is empty

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

Here is my code:

```html
<h:inputText size="22" 
    value="#{bean.searchString}"
    id="drugName">

    <a4j:support
        actionListener="#{bean.searchMedication}"
        ajaxSingle="true" reRender="contentListGrid"
        event="onkeyup" id="searchAjax" 
        requestDelay="200" 
        rendered="#{bean.searchString.length() > 0}">
    </a4j:support>
</h:inputText>
```

I would like to prevent the `a4j:support` call whenever the input field is not filled out. I tried it by determining the input value length in the `rendered` attribute. However, it results in the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/medication/MedicationList.jsp(147,9) The function length must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor$1FVVisitor.visit(Validator.java:1478)
```

What does this message mean?

> The function length must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Can't we invoke a method in EL?

Comment: You know that there is no `size()` method for string, don't you?

Comment: Opps!! Let me change I mean length() 

>  The function length must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Above error is coming in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the concrete exception, invoking non-property methods (i.e. non-getter/setter methods) is only supported since EL 2.2 which is part of Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2. You seem to be using old JSF 1.x and thus also old Servlet 2.5 / JSP 2.1. Basically you end up with an EL syntax error.

Actually, you don't need EL 2.2 for this. Just use `empty` keyword instead.

```
rendered="#{not empty bean.searchString}"
```

However this approach won't work as well. The `rendered` attribute will be examined in the server side when the HTML code is to be generated and sent to the browser, not during the client side events as you seem to expect (rightclick page in browser, *View Source*, do you see any JSF code?). You need to use JavaScript to check the input value length in the `onkeyup` of the field or `onsubmit` of the Ajax call and return `false` accordingly.

```html
<h:inputText ... onkeyup="return (!!value)">
```

or (not guaranteed that this works, I don't know off top of head what markup it generates)

```html
<h:inputText ...>
    <a4j:support ... onsubmit="return (!!value)" />
</h:inputText>
```

The first `!` converts it to inversed `boolean` and the second `!` re-inverses it. This way you end up with a fullworthy `boolean` return outcome depending on the presence of any value. If it's `false`, then the remaining `onkeyup` functions (such as you've specified with `<a4j:support>`) will be blocked.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your answer but after using this even it calls the ajax.

Comment: Oh, I missed that functional requirement. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Read BalusC answer.

You can do that also on client side, by first checking if the value is empty or not:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.searchString}" id="drugName">
    <a4j:support onsubmit="if ($F('theFormID:drugName') == '') { return false; }"
    .../>
</h:inputText>
```

(`$F('someId')` is equivalent to `document.getElementById('someId').value`, with Prototype JavaScript library, which is included in Richfaces).

Comment: Thanks romaintaz for your quick answer. I tried this but when I am using $F and this code it stopped calling ajax. and webconsol of firefox says $F is not defined. Am I using it in wrong way?

Comment: You can try `if ($('yourFormID:drugName').value == '') { ...`